# Why is selenium ide adding additional \'s to my file location?

Tags: file, selenium, file-upload, ide, selenium-ide

I am trying to add a file to selenium IDE from a shared network location. When I type in the location of the file then click on another command in the case it adds extra \ to the file location which results in the file not being uploaded.

\\qtc-nas.citicus.com\backups\CB\test.txt

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

You need to escape the slashes:

```
[info] Executing: |store | \\xyz\abc\ | c |
[info] Executing: |echo | ${c} | |
[info] echo: \\xyz\abc\
```